# CellValueChanged on DataTable/ programatically added DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, loops, for-loop

I'm having some problem with CellValueChanged.

I can do it this way and it works :

```
    private void dataGridView_etykietyA6_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        //do some stuff
    }
```

But I had to add my DataGridView manually then, but I want to add them by :

```
        for (int i = 0; i < lista.Count; i++)
        {
            tabControl_Roz.TabPages.Add("Typ "+lista[i]);
            tabControl_Roz.TabPages[i + 1].Controls.Add(new DataGridView()
            {
                Name = "dataGridView_" + lista[i],
                Dock = DockStyle.Fill
            });
        }
```

DataGridView adding works correctly but I don't know how to use CellValueChanged on it.

So is there any chance to use CellValueChanged 
on this programatically added DataGridView or if it's not possible is there any chance to do it on DataTable?

Anyone know good way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add event handlers programmatically with `+=` operator like this:

```
var dataGridView = new DataGridView()
{
    Name = "dataGridView_" + lista[i],
    Dock = DockStyle.Fill
};
dataGridView.CellValueChanged += new EventHandler(dataGridView_etykietyA6_CellValueChanged); // this is the name of your handler method
tabControl_Roz.TabPages[i + 1].Controls.Add(dataGridView);
```

or you can even write your handler logic inline like this:

```
dataGridView.CellValueChanged += (e, sender) => {
// your handler logic
};
```

Comment: I'm having an error with dataGridView.CellValueChanged += new EventHandler(dataGridView_ety_CellValueChanged). Which tells me "No overload for 'dataGridView_ety_CellValueChanged' matches delegate 'EventHandler''

Comment: Try `+= new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(..)`.